# Laravel user has to be logged in at least 5 times to acces page

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making  a blog in laravel. You can only create posts if you as user have logged in at least 5 times. I have made a logincounter, which works. Using the following code in my logincontroller:

```js
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {

        $user->logincount++;
        $user->save();

    }
```

If I log in 5 times, it shows 5 in the database. Now, i want to create a function that checks if I have logged in 5 times or more before directing me to the /create page. The function I tried to put in the postcontroller doesn't work:

```js
public function create(){
$user = User::all();
        if ($user->logincount > 5) {

            return view('create');
        }
    }
```

The error I get is the following: Property [logincount] does not exist on this collection instance.

This does not work, Laravel doesn't recognize logincount even after I put use App/Model/User. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like `$user` is defined in `create`

Comment: @aynber he does find user but doesnt seem to find logincount

Comment: What's the error, and how are you defining `$user` in the function?

Comment: *doesn't work* isn't very helpful by itself. Please include what you're observing vs what you expect. Is there an error? Is the property undefined? null?

Comment: apologies, I updated the question with  the error I'm getting if I try to run my own code

Comment: `User::all()` returns a collection of ALL users, not a single user. To get the current authenticated user, you need `$user = Auth::user();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set your $user variable ?
Like `$user = \Auth::user()` for example

Comment: $user = User::all(); is what I used. It  does not work

Comment: Try `$user = \Auth::user();`

Comment: Elias you have fixed my problem and you are my hero of the day. Thanks!